# Что-то не получается с циклом foreach в теге html

Tags: php, php7

Вроде все правильно но все равно вылазит ошибка

`Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\webalize\template\index.php on line 75
Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\webalize\template\index.php on line 76
Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\webalize\template\index.php on line 77
Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\webalize\template\index.php on line 77`

Вот мой файл index.php

```
<?php
$data = require_once 'data.php';

$educationData = $data['education'];

?>
 <h2 class="container-block-title">Education</h2>
            <? foreach ($educationData as $value){ ?>
                <div class="item">
                    <h4 class="degree"><?php $value['courses']?></h4>
                    <h5 class="meta"><?php $value['training']?></h5>
                    <div class="time"><?php $value['yearStart']?>  - <?php $value['yearEnd']?></div>
                </div><!--//item-->
            <?php}?>
```

Ошибка вот здесь

```
               ` <h4 class="degree"><?php $value['courses']?></h4>
                <h5 class="meta"><?php $value['training']?></h5>
                <div class="time"><?php $value['yearStart']?>  - <?php 
                $value['yearEnd']?></div>`
```

Мой файл data.php

```
      `<?php 
       return [

     'education' => [
    [
        'courses' => 'SEO courses',
        'training' => 'Cursor, Kiev Training Center ',
        'yearStart' => 2018,
        'yearEnd' => 2019
    ],
    [
        'courses' => 'Web UI Basics',
        'training' => 'Lviv IT School - Prometheus',
       'yearStart' => 2019,
        'yearEnd' => 2019
    ],
    [
        'courses' => 'Web Frontend Developer',
        'training' => 'CyberBionic Systematics ',
        'yearStart' => 2019,
        'yearEnd' => 2019
      ]
      ]
     ];`
```

Comment: а какие это строки 75-77 ?

Comment: вы ничего не выводите, но если добавить echo, все отлично работает - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cdaca3df5e798621b17a8a0e99012fb3284f3293

Comment: Пробывал все равно та же ошибка

Comment: на каких строках ошибка?

Comment: Пишет на этих  <h4 class="degree"><?php echo $value['courses']?></h4>
                        <h5 class="meta"><?php echo $value['training']?></h5>
                        <div class="time"><?php echo $value['yearStart']?>  - <?php echo $value['yearEnd']?></div>

Comment: Это не ошибка в строках. Это сообщение, что переменная не определена( не существует).  
первое что надо сделать - `var_dump($educationData);` Про `echo` вам сказали. А дальше уже думать.

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev переменная `$value` создается в цикле, ошибка в том что тут смешан и альтернативный синтаксис и обычный, либо добавить `php` после открывающего тега `<?` либо изменить `}` на `:` и `endforeach` соответственно

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($educationData as $value){ ?>
                <div class="item">
                    <h4 class="degree"><?php echo $value['courses']?></h4>
                    <h5 class="meta"><?php echo $value['training']?></h5>
                    <div class="time"><?php echo $value['yearStart']?>  - <?php echo $value['yearEnd']?></div>
                </div><!--//item-->
            <?php } ?>
```

Вы определитесь хотите использовать альтернативный синтаксис или нет. Добавьте `php` перед `foreach` как я показал

Comment: Вывод переменных то добавьте

Comment: После того как я поменял вылетела ошибка     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\webalize\template\index.php on line 251

Comment: что находится на строке 251?

Comment: Там находится конец php

Comment: то есть у вас там находится `?>` но открывающего тега нет?

Comment: Спасибо!!! Действительно надо было echo добавить

Comment: @EvgenRoev если вам помог мой ответ, то установите его решением

Answer (score 0):

$educationData это массив из одного элемента, который уже состоит из нескольких

```
<?php

$educationData = ['education' => [
    [
        'courses' => 'SEO courses',
        'training' => 'Cursor, Kiev Training Center ',
        'yearStart' => 2018,
        'yearEnd' => 2019
    ],
    [
        'courses' => 'Web UI Basics',
        'training' => 'Lviv IT School - Prometheus',
       'yearStart' => 2019,
        'yearEnd' => 2019
    ],
    [
        'courses' => 'Web Frontend Developer',
        'training' => 'CyberBionic Systematics ',
        'yearStart' => 2019,
        'yearEnd' => 2019
      ]
    ]
];



foreach ($educationData as $v){ 
    foreach ($v as $value){ ?>
            <div class="item">
                <h4 class="degree"><?=$value['courses']?></h4>
                <h5 class="meta"><?=$value['training']?></h5>
                <div class="time"><?=$value['yearStart']?>  - <?=$value['yearEnd']?></div>
            </div>
    <?}?>        
<?}?>


            <div class="item">
                <h4 class="degree">SEO courses</h4>
                <h5 class="meta">Cursor, Kiev Training Center </h5>
                <div class="time">2018  - 2019</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h4 class="degree">Web UI Basics</h4>
                <h5 class="meta">Lviv IT School - Prometheus</h5>
                <div class="time">2019  - 2019</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h4 class="degree">Web Frontend Developer</h4>
                <h5 class="meta">CyberBionic Systematics </h5>
                <div class="time">2019  - 2019</div>
            </div>
```